# Why selenium.write writes new code to file?

Tags: html, webdriver

Good day, I need to save a few hundred pins on Pinterest. For this I use the variable kol_of_iter = 10.
That is, for 200 pins, 10 iterations each, 20 pins from the page.The code parses each iteration anew, writing the html code to a file

try:
driver.get(url=url)
time.sleep(3)

```
    while True:
        with open("MainParser.html", 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
                
                while i <= kol_of_iter:
                    file.write(driver.page_source)
                    scroll_by = f'window.scrollBy(1, {scroll_vаlue});'
                    driver.execute_script(scroll_by)
                    time.sleep(1)
                    file.write(driver.page_source)
                    i += 1      
        break     
        
except Exception as _ex:
    print(_ex)
```